# JavaScript Performance issue with API calls (React Native, Google Calendar API)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, performance, asynchronous

I'm developing an app using React Native, Expo Stack and having a performance issue with my list component.

The structure is as below

**List consists of Items**

```
data.map(d => (<Item />));
```

**Item contains multiple cell component, and one of them is the "Upcoming" component**

```
const Upcoming = ({...props}) => {
   
   const [schedules, setSchedules] = useState([]);

   useEffect(()=> {
     _pullSchedule().then(data => { setSchedules(data) }
   },[]);

return (<View>//Latest events shown here</View>)

}
```

**_pullSchedule function which gets all the event associated with the Item**

```
const _pullSchedule = async (
  schedule,
  item,
  updateItem,
  user,
  users,
  all = false
) => {
  let schedules = [];

  await Promise.all(
    schedule.map(async (s, i) => {
      try {
        const res = await getEvent(s.calId, s.id);
        if (res && res.data && res.data.summary) {
          schedules.push(res.data);
        } else {
          schedules.push({
            event: {
              status: "cancelled",
              summary: "unknown",
              htmlLink: "unknown",
              id: s.id,
            },
          });
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    })
  );

  let cleaned = schedule;

  let history = [];
  if (item.history && item.history.length > 0) {
    history = item.history;
  }

  schedules.forEach((event, i) => {
    if (event.status == "cancelled" || event.start == undefined) {
      cleaned = cleaned.filter(v => v.id !== event.id);

      history.push({
        type: "schedule",
        message: "Event cancelled : " + event.summary,
        status: {
          num: item.status.is.num,
          name: item.status.is.name,
        },
        link: event.htmlLink,
        date: new Date(),
        by: user._id,
      });
    }
  });

  let update = [
    {
      where: "schedule",
      data: cleaned,
    },
    {
      where: "history",
      data: history,
    },
  ];

  if (cleaned.length !== schedule.length) {
    updateItem(update, item._id, true);
  }

  schedules = schedules
    .filter(s => s.status !== "cancelled" && s.start !== undefined)
    .map(event => {
      let theDate, theStart, theEnd;

      let theType = "dateTime";
      if (event.start.dateTime) {
        theDate = new Date(event.start.dateTime);
        theStart = new Date(event.start.dateTime);
        theEnd = new Date(event.end.dateTime);
      } else {
        theDate = new Date(event.start.date);
        theStart = new Date(event.start.date);
        theEnd = new Date(event.end.date);
        theType = "date";
      }

      let summary = event.summary.replace(/\[(.*?)\] /, "");
      summary = summary.replace(item.client + " / ", "");

      const by =
        users[users.findIndex(v => v.calId == event.organizer.email)].firstName;

      return {
        summary: summary,
        id: event.id,
        calId: event.organizer.email,
        date: theDate,
        start: theStart,
        end: theEnd,
        link: event.htmlLink,
        type: theType,
        description: event.description,
        by: by,
      };
    });

  schedules = schedules.sort((a, b) => {
    return Date.parse(b.date) - Date.parse(a.date);
  });

  if (all) {
    return schedules;
  }

  schedules = schedules
    .filter(v => Date.parse(v.end) - Date.parse(new Date()) > 0)
    .sort((a, b) => {
      return Date.parse(a.date) - Date.parse(b.date);
    });

  if (schedules.length > 0) {
    return schedules[0];
  }
};
```

**getEvent API Call from FrontEnd to server**

```
export const getEvent = async (calId, id) => {
  const endpoint = api + "/calendar/event/" + calId + "/" + id;
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(endpoint);
    return res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

**API call to Google from Server**

```
router.get("/event/:calId/:id", auth("Cal_GET_Event"), async (req, res) => {
  const { calId, id } = req.params;
  try {
    calendar.events.get(
      {
        calendarId: calId,
        eventId: id,
      },
      (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log("Server Error: " + error);
          res.status(500).send("Server error: " + error);
        } else {
          res.json(result);
        }
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server error");
  }
});
```

**Network Capture of Chrome Devtools, basically there are about 2~300 requests made to Google Calendar on each load**

[image: Network Capture]

Now the problem is that with multiple items containing multiple events, say about 100,
it makes a lot of requests which block the event loop I believe.

The reason why I believe so is due to the below facts.

- When these calendar API calls are not complete, even if you refresh, it won't proceed to make new API calls, which means, even when the component is unmounted, the API call is affecting the app's performance.
- Basically same as above, but any actions that include API call to the server will not be made before these calendar API calls are complete.

I'm not sure why these supposedly synchronous API calls are behaving so.

If anyone can help me out with this, it will be super appreciated.
This is the only thing that is holding me back from using this app..!

Comment: Just to be clearer, 100~200 requests made to Google is not the problem as it is intended. The problem is that it blocks other operations. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The core of the React Native is React JS, and everytime a `<Item />` renders, every component inside `<Item />` will render again and again, so if the "data" array length is 5, then, `<item />` will render 5 times so the "Upcoming" component and the useEffect inside of it will also run each time.

Comment: Hi Neel, thanks for the input, however the Upcoming component is being rendered only once when it's parent Item component is rendered, the Upcoming component only re renders when its Item data or schedule change is detected.